# How to compile efivar 0.24?

Tags: compiling, libraries, uefi

I am having trouble compiling [efivar 0.24](https://github.com/rhinstaller/efivar/releases/tag/0.24) and have already searched on StackExchange for an answer I found one close [How to compile efivar?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278727/how-to-compile-efivar/278731) but it didn't exactly solve my problem. `make V=1 -j1`

I get an error saying

```
root:/sources/efivar-0.24/src# make V=1 -j1
make -f /sources/efivar-0.24/src/Make.deps deps SOURCES="crc32.c creator.c disk.c gpt.c linux.c loadopt.c dp.c dp-acpi.c dp-hw.c dp-media.c dp-message.c efivarfs.c export.c guid.c guids.S guid-symbols.c lib.c vars.c makeguids.c guid.c include/efivar/efivar-guids.h include/efivar/efivar.h include/efivar/efiboot.h include/efivar/efiboot-loadopt.h include/efivar/efivar-dp.h include/efivar/efiboot-creator.h include/efivar/efivar-guids.h guid-symbols.c efivar.c"
make[1]: Entering directory '/sources/efivar-0.24/src'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'deps'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/sources/efivar-0.24/src'
gcc -O2 -g3 -I/sources/efivar-0.24/src/include/efivar/  -specs=/sources/efivar-0.24/gcc.specs  -L.      -static -I/usr/include -o efivar-static efivar.c dp.static.o dp-acpi.static.o dp-hw.static.o dp-media.static.o dp-message.static.o efivarfs.static.o export.static.o guid.static.o guids.static.o guid-symbols.static.o lib.static.o vars.static.o -ldl -lpopt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpopt
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/sources/efivar-0.24/Make.rules:17: efivar-static] Error 1
```

I have checked the Make.Defaults which contains

```
prefix  ?= /usr/
libdir  ?= $(prefix)/lib64/
datadir ?= $(prefix)/share/
mandir  ?= $(datadir)/man/
includedir ?= $(prefix)/include/
bindir  ?= $(prefix)/bin/
PCDIR   ?= $(libdir)/pkgconfig/
DESTDIR ?=
```

I have also searched for popt.h and popt.pc to make sure they were in the correct directories.

```
root:/sources/efivar-0.24/src# find / -iname popt.h
/usr/include/popt.h
root:/sources/efivar-0.24/src# find / -iname popt.pc
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/popt.pc
```

/usr/lib/pkgconfig/popt.pc has an output of

```
prefix=/usr
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: popt
Version: 1.16
Description: popt library.
Libs: -L${libdir} -lpopt
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

If someone could help me with figuring out a fix or at least point me in a direction I should be looking at that would be awesome. Thank you in advance guys and girls.

Comment: You probably need to run the `make` command in the `/sources/efivar-0.24/` directory, not `/sources/efivar-0.24/src`, unless there are docs stating otherwise.

Comment: @Munir `gcc -O2 -g3 -I/sources/efivar-0.24/src/include/efivar/  -specs=/sources/efivar-0.24/gcc.specs  -L.      -static -I/usr/include -o efivar-static efivar.c dp.static.o dp-acpi.static.o dp-hw.static.o dp-media.static.o dp-message.static.o efivarfs.static.o export.static.o guid.static.o guids.static.o guid-symbols.static.o lib.static.o vars.static.o -ldl -lpopt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpopt
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/sources/efivar-0.24/Make.rules:17: efivar-static] Error 1`

Same result in src or in the main directory after running make clean for both.

Comment: What distro / flavor of *nix? The obvious question would seem to be is there actually a `libpopt.so.xx` file in the directory indicated by the .pc file i.e. `/usr/lib/`?

Comment: @steeldriver it is a Linux From Scratch using x86_64.

`-rwxr-xr-x - /usr/lib/libpopt.la
lrwxrwxrwx - /usr/lib/libpopt.so -> libpopt.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx - /usr/lib/libpopt.so.0 -> libpopt.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x - /usr/lib/libpopt.so.0.0.0`

Comment: I just noticed you are building with the `-static` switch - but I don't see a `libpopt.a` among the files in your comment (just the libtool `.la` file)

Comment: @steeldriver OMG Thank you! Since the Makefile of efivar 0.24 has -static built in I didn't even realize that until you mentioned it... I have since compiled  popt with the static option enabled and ran the make for efivar again and it ran smoothly.